# How to find where is memory leak in a flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks

How to find where is memory leak in a flex application?

Are there some tools to catch and analyze this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Profiler tool to view your application's resource utilization over time.

How to use the Profiler: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_4.html